# Do we know "The Midwife"'s real name?

Tags: finnish-language, katja-kettu, the-midwife

In *The Midwife* by Katja Kettu, many of the characters have different aliases. By the end of the book we have enough information to identify most of the characters, such as "Scarface", "Redhead", "The Jerker", "The Merchant" and so on. The one exception is the central character, the midwife herself. She is known to the local villagers as "the Red bastard" or the "Weird-Eye", to her German lover as "Wild-Eye", and at the prison camp as "Fräulein Schwester". I assume that this last is an honorific rather than her name, akin to calling a nurse "Sister".

We do discover that her father's name was Pietari Kutilainen, which should tell us her surname (*). But are there any clues in the novel that reveal her first name?

<sub>* Although as her parents were not married, I do not know if she would have taken her father's surname.</sub>